# I need to extract BMP hex color values and export them to a txt file.

Tags: hex

I want to convert a BMP to a TXT with the pixel data on each line.

here is what i am looking to extract: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o8Ck.jpg

Is there a simple way to do this? I have been using color picker the hard way and need to extract a series of 1x100 pixel images.

I am importing this into a spreadsheet, each image as a column of cells with the hex data.

Comment: What OS or programming language can you use?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. considering extracting them writing a code using a jpg  library - it's usually installed in linux (needed to install libjpeg-devel package - on a Fedora here it's called libjpeg-turbo-devel).
2. load the jpeg into **gimp**, then export it to a [*.ppm* file](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html). gimp will let you to export it as binary or ascii file. In the first case you can just dump it with something similar to `od -x`

Comment: I tried the ppm, but get a non-hex dump. Best luck I had was to export to HTML and parse the "#******"... but if there can be a dump with the HTML with the hex, seems like there should be a simpler was to just get the HEX. I am working in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Hey not sure if this is something you're still trying to do but:

I'm doing a similar thing, I need to extract the pixel data from a .bmp in order to generate a .mif or .hex file for VGA interfacing via FPGA.

Now my process so far has been to first resave my .bmp's as RGB16 resolution, this is just a personal preference as my VGA driver is setup to take #0000 four character hex values (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue).

Anyway, after the image is set up I open it in gimp and then export as a .ppm with ASCII format. This gives me decimal values for each pixel but my plan is to write a simple script to convert these to hex. One thing I'll mention though, I haven't confirmed this yet but I know that bmp files draw bottom to top, left to right. Whether or not this is reflected in the pixel data will be seen but if it is there's two options:

1) Again write a script to reorder the data (tedious)

2) Flip the image in paint (easier)

Hope this helps :)